# Google Custom search JS Syntax error

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

My Google custom search is stuck forever loading.
The JS error I get in the Chrome console is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'enableSearchBoxOnly'
```

My code:

```
    <div class="search">
<div id='cse-search-form' style='width: 100%;'>Loading</div>
</div>
<script src='//www.google.com/jsapi' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
google.load('search', '1', {language: 'es', style: google.loader.themes.DEFAULT});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
var customSearchOptions = {};
var customSearchControl =   new google.search.CustomSearchControl('003806993800906102968:1a2oqwxzgqk', customSearchOptions);
customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
options.enableSearchBoxOnly('https://www.globalsign.es/buscar', 'q');
customSearchControl.draw('cse-search-form', options);
}, true);
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/cselement-reference#csedrawoptions-el) indicates that `enableSearchBoxOnly` is mis-capitalized.  Try

```
options.enableSearchboxOnly('https://www.globalsign.es/buscar', 'q');
```

instead of starting "box" with a capital b.

```
options.enableSearchBoxOnly('https://www.globalsign.es/buscar', 'q');
                    ^
```

Comment: @Barney, I'd file a bug with them.  Do you happen to know where you found the sample code?

Comment: Yeah it's from the Google custom search page - V1 of the search engine. I shall file a bug this week :)